# Running python in powershell crashes

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell

I am learning python from the book *Learn Python the Hardway*. I tried running python in powershell and python crashes.

```
PS C:\python27>Fatal Python error:
    Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
        File ".\lib\encodings\__init__.py, line 123
            raise CodecRegistryError,\
                   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I have tried reinstalling several versions of python. Please tell me a way to fix this.

Comment: I can start python (2.7 and 3.5) in 64-bit Win10 PowerShell, but just yesterday a read a Windows expert saying that python may not run in PS because of standard stream init problem.  So you may need to either upgrade Windows or use Command Prompt.

Comment: stakcoverflow's not the "application's support team".

Comment: Are you running the latest version of 2.7, 2.7.12?  The error message is strange.  There is no SyntaxError in encodings/__init__.py, at least not as installed on my machine.  The Win expert hinted that problems might depend on the encodings code page

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you have tried using cmd.exe (the command prompt) (which you can run by pressing the windows key + R and then typing cmd). It might be a bug. When I looked at the Python [issue trackers](https://bugs.python.org/issue10920), it seems that something like this has happened before. You could try dual-booting Linux, or using [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com), which allows you to use a Linux shell on your Windows machine.